# Reply in ephemeral message to a user's message

Tags: javascript, discord.js

is it possible for a bot to reply to a user's message and the reply would be in ephemeral? like, if `user1` sends a message the bot will automatically respond in ephemeral. only asking if this is possible if the user didn't do any sort of interaction with the bot

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Bots can only send ephemeral responses when replying to an interaction** (slash command, button interaction, select menu, etc.) - it is not possible to send an ephemeral message when replying to a message without an interaction.

The discord.js documentation can provides useful information regarding this: [discord.js.org | CommandInteraction/ephemeral](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/CommandInteraction?scrollTo=ephemeral)

You can also read more in the discord.js guide here (note how it is specifically under the slash commands section): [discord.js guide | Slash Commands/Ephemeral Responses](https://discordjs.guide/slash-commands/response-methods.html#ephemeral-responses)

Hope this helps clear things up.